# Java thinks C:\ drive is hidden?

Tags: java, file, undefined-behavior

I think it's better if I explain the situation first.

### Situation

I'm writing a bit of software that filters through a `Set` of `File`s.

The filter is the following: If the file is NOT hidden, then add it it to the new `Set`.

The problem is that the current behaviour of `File.isHidden()` is as follows:

```
File f = new File("C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Temp\REG28E.tmp");
System.out.println(f.isHidden());
```

The program will output `false`.

The file itself (`REG28E.tmp`) is NOT actually hidden. Rather, a certain folder in the *path to it* is hidden (`Local Settings`).

I want to create a bit of code that will check:

If, somewhere along the path to the file is hidden, then the file is marked as hidden.

I've come up with the following solution to check the file's path recursively:

```
boolean hidden = file.isHidden();
File parentFile = file.getParentFile();
while ((hidden == false) || (parentFile != null)) {
    hidden = parentFile.isHidden();
    parentFile = parentFile.getParentFile();
}

if (!hidden) {
    acceptedFileList.add(file);
}
```

### The Problem

And finally, we come to the problem. I can never get to the stage where I'm actually adding files. The problem is that Java thinks that the C:\ drive **itself** is hidden!

What can I do instead?

Comment: What OS are you using? XP or 7? What happens when you visit C:\ in Windows Explorer? Also look at the Security tab on the properties for the drive.

Comment: I'm programming in a Virtual Machine running Windows XP.  What should I be looking for? There is no Security tab on the Drive's properties.

Comment: Assuming you are checking the path recursively, just hardcode `C:/` to `false` (not hidden). Problem solved, hehe.

Comment: @RosdiKasim that helped me arrive at my solution, so thanks!

Comment: C:\ is a directory, not a drive. Any directory can be hidden.

Comment: @hovercraftfullofeels Wow, Java still does this... really strange behavior. 12 years later. Anyone found the reason why Java does this? Java 20 still does this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution involved adding a manual check to see whether the `parentFile` object is a root directory or not.

```
while ((hidden == false) && (parentFile != null)) {
    // added the IF statement below:
    if (FileSystemUtils.isRoot(parentFile)) {
        hidden = false;
        break;
    }

    hidden = parentFile.isHidden();
    parentFile = parentFile.getParentFile();
}
```

---

#### Checking if Root directory

The above code makes use of a FileSystemUtils class. It contains the following method:

```
public static boolean isRoot(File file) {
    File[] roots = File.listRoots();

    for (File root : roots) {
        if (file.equals(root)) {
        return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Thanks to all who chimed in...

Comment: To check if a path is root, you can also use this: `path.getRoot().equals(path);` (use `topath()` to convert from File-object to Path).

Answer (score 1):

My guess is your while condition needs the `&&` operator instead of `||` (It probably caused some NPE).
Try:

```
while (!hidden && (parentFile != null)) {...
```